# Task: Import csv, xml files into new Schema. Displaying reports. JAVA

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, csv, report

I have a task to do. Just for practice. Would you please give ma any advises how to start it ( I am not begging for a code :) )
What should I do? Any suggestions, hints?

1. Import list of files csv, xml.
2. Every order I have to write in (in-memory) database
3. The order should have fields like: Client_Id, Name, Price etc....
4. Program has to generate reports e.g.: quantity of orders, average amount of order, total amount of orders etc.
5. Every raport can be displayed or written to (any) file
6. Database can not be divided between every start-up
7. Incorrect lines in order are ignored but the information about bad format is displayed.

the csv and xml files contains e.g.:

```
>Client_id,Other_id,Name,Amount
> 1,1,Joe,25, 
> 1,2,Mike,34 
> 2,2,Maria,10 
> 2,1,Elizabeth,5
> 
> xml <reuqests>   <request>
>       <client_id>1</client_Id>
>       <name>Joe</name> etc.......
>     </request>
>     </requests>
```

What I might know is:
1. Import csv using csvopen. Sounds easy but, do I need to import them separately or can I use the List
2/3 Can I create schema using hibernate?
4 ? I am not sure. Can I use "switch"? 
5. What library can I use to write reports? (Can I use Jesper Reports?)
6/7 What does it mean?

Comment: What's the desired output, `xml` or `csv` or other?